# Javascript ParseInt() with -1

Tags: javascript, parseint

can someone tell me why this `var val="08";  alert(parseInt(val-1));` shows 7
but `var val="08";  alert(parseInt(val)-1);` shows -1 ?

Thnx

Comment: No repro here on Firefox 26. Invalid octal literals such as `08` are tricky to work with, their support depends on the browser. Best to avoid them.

Comment: I tried in Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63. It is giving 7 in both the cases. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfu7t/

Comment: Which browser (and version) are you using? In the first case, the string is implicitly converted to a number first, *before* the result of `val - 1` (`7`) is passed to `parseInt` and in the second example, `val` is first passed to `parseInt` and as result converted to a number. That's the difference and that's why you get different outputs in browsers that still implement the old `parseInt` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt("08")` will give you `NaN` if the engine you're using extends `parseInt` to recognize octal (the leading `0` means "octal"). It will give you `8` if the engine follows the standard, which says not to do that (as of ES5).

`parseInt("08"-1)` is a bit redundant, because the expression `"08"-1` will result in a number (which then gets passed into `parseInt`); just `"08"-1` is all you need. Here's how that breaks down:

- The engine processes the expression `"08" - 1` by trying to turn `"08"` into a number. On an engine that extends numeric literal syntax to include octal, that would fail, but on engines that don't, it will give you `8`. So the result of the expression is the *number* 7 (8 - 1).
- The engine then does `parseInt(7)`, which is redundant, as `7` is already a number. What happens is that `7` is turned into `"7"` and then parsed back into `7`.

Note the difference above: The result of `parseInt("08") - 1` will vary based on whether the engine extends what `parseInt` will parse, but the result of `"08" - 1` will vary based on whether the engine extends numeric literal syntax. Those are two different things, and the [ES5 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) does not allow engines to extend `parseInt`'s syntax, but *does* allow them to extend numeric literal syntax (see [§B.1.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1)), but only in loose mode. (Confusing, I know.)

The take-away message: Always use a radix with `parseInt` to tell it what number base to use.

Answer (score 1):

Always use `parseInt(val,10);` to ensure that value is parsed in decimal system.
In your case when you alert `val-1` i.e. `08-1` so it is `7` i.e. `parseInt(7) ==> 7`

but when you do

```
parseInt(val)-1  ==> parseInt("08")-1 ==> 0-1 ==> -1
```

why it becomes `0` ?
The answer is it assumes you want to parse in Octal number system.

So always use the second argument i.e. `parseInt(whatevervalue,10);`